# Rubyinstaller for Windows - ruby does nothing

Tags: ruby, windows, rubyinstaller

I've tried using Ruby 2.0 x64 and Ruby 1.9.3 for Windows using RubyInstaller. Entering `ruby -v` works as expected, and running `gem` gives me the expected usage docs.  Running and using the Interactive Ruby application works as expected.  I am running Windows 8.1 Update.

However, for both installations, running `ruby` from cmd gives me a blank prompt where I can type, but nothing is executed when I press enter.  If I attempt to install a gem, there is a similar issue where the program is running, but there is absolutely no output, and nothing happens.

I can't seem to be able to find a similar issue elsewhere.  Does anyone know what might be wrong, and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect to happen?  ruby.exe is the ruby interpreter, meant for running ruby scripts. Normally, to use it you would create a file containing valid ruby commands with your favorite text editor (but ***not*** a word processor). If you save the file as `foobar.rb`, typing `ruby foobar.rb` (or if you told the installer to associate .rb files with ruby, typing just `foobar.rb`) will execute the commands in the file as a script/program. If you don't supply a script file name, ruby goes into input mode and expects you to type in a program on the spot. It won't give any feedback until you indicate end-of-file by typing CTRL-z, at which point it will process what you typed and most likely tell you about all the errors you made. If you want line-by-line interactive feedback, use `irb`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I was expecting ruby to behave as Python would have.  I had the same problem with `gem` still, but after letting it sit for a while, I found out that I actually needed to install the ruby devkit.  `gem` seems to have installed rails properly now.